# Inventory product computation and conversion

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal

I am coding inventory of products. Now I am in the process of computing or converting the items into a larger unit.

For example:
Product A: 1 box = 12 bottles

The user can input a data like 3 boxes and 13 bottles when adding a transaction. And the new value for Product A will be `3 boxes and 13 bottles in storage`. Data will save into database `tbl_transaction`.

How can I automatically turn/convert the items as a whole like `4 boxes and 1 bottle in storage` to add in my `tbl_storage`?

I have tried this formula but I am afraid it is not accurate when the number of bottles is in the decimal point.

```
$bottles = 13;
$box = 12; 
$remaining_in_bottle = number_format($bottles / $box);// this will only convert the bottle into box (also tried float but not sure what I am doing)
$total_box = 3 + ???; 

echo $total_box." boxes and ".$remaining_in_bottle ." bottles in storage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the user is inputing just digits as values for `boxes` and `bottles`, but if not you will simply need to extract these values from the string before performing the following calculations:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0507f24be176b20c2af03f64086f097bb059c452))

```
$bottles_per_box=12; 

$user_input_bottles=13;
$user_input_boxes=3;

if($user_input_bottles>$bottles_per_box){
    // add truncated integer to box count.  DO NOT USE ROUND(), USE FLOOR()
    $user_input_boxes+=floor($user_input_bottles/$bottles_per_box);

    // store remainder after division
    $user_input_bottles=$user_input_bottles%$bottles_per_box;
    //                                     ^-- modulo operator
}

echo "New Bottles Total: $user_input_bottles\n";
echo "New Boxes Total: $user_input_boxes\n";
```

Output:

```
New Bottles Total: 1
New Boxes Total: 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your input and solution. Very simple. Cheers! I hope I know how to use `%` when getting the remainder.

Comment: Is it possible that the result of the remainder would be in decimal?

Comment: When using `floor()` you are effectively dropping any decimal values from the number.  `1.9` becomes `1` and `2.1` becomes `2`.  This is why `floor()` is required and `round()` will provide incorrect results.  When using the `modulo operator` you will be seeking ONLY the remainder value.  e.g. `13/12` has a remainder of `1` (no decimals to work with).

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to input different for `tbl_transaction` and `tbl_storage`.

**CODE**

```
//Max bottle per box
$box_max_bottles = 12;

//User Input
$input_box = 3; 
$input_bottle = 13;

//Transaction
$transaction  = (($input_box > 1) ? $input_box . ' boxes' : $input_box . ' box') 
                . ' and ' . (($input_bottle > 1) ? $input_bottle. ' bottles' : $input_bottle. ' bottle'). ' in storage';

//Data will save into database tbl_transaction
echo $transaction;

//Get the remainder which is the remaining bottle
$total_bottle = $input_bottle % 12;

//Get the total boxes and divide the bottle into 12 
$total_box = floor($input_box + ($input_bottle / 12));

echo "<br />";

//Storage
$storage  = (($total_box > 1) ? $total_box . ' boxes' : $total_box . ' box') 
                . ' and ' . (($total_bottle > 1) ? $total_bottle . ' bottles' : $total_bottle . ' bottle'). ' in storage';

//Data will save into database tbl_storage
echo $storage;
```

**OUTPUT**

*Transaction*

```
3 boxes and 13 bottles in storage
```

*Storage*

```
4 boxes and 1 bottle in storage
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it. You and  mickmackusa have the right solution but I am accepting the answer and solution of mickmackusa, because it is more applicable to my situation. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest, this is not a correct method -- at least because of `round()` I didn't test the code, but `round()` is not right.  Please read my answer and update yours.

Comment: @mickmackusa You're right. I read your answer and `floor()` should be use instead since `round()` will round up if .5+ .and might produce not correct output in future. Didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that.